# I want to keep on storing and displaying the result I am getting from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I am not an expert at php just a newbie so not sure what to do.What I am trying to do is to keep on saving the result I am getting from the textbox[This is the textbox and shirt,color and price is the result I am getting from the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ3aN.jpg) and keep on displaying it on my page. The picture for the textbox is attached. I want to keep on storing the new result I get from the table and also keep displaying the old one. I hope its clear what I am trying to do. My code has three files the main file products.php has the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Products</title>
    <p> Scan the Barcode of the Product </p>
    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

        <input type="text" name="enter" required id="item" style="text-align:centre" placeholder=" Barcode ID" autofocus />

        <div id="item-data"></div>

        <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> <!--jquery link-->
        <script src="js/global.js"></script> <!--linking event file-->

</body>
</html>
```

while code for global.js is

```
$(function(){

//press enter on text area..

$('#item').keypress(function (event) {
var key = event.which;
if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
{

var item = $('input#item').val();    // retreiving the value from the item
    if ($.trim(item) != ''){            //send this to php file but if its     empty or spaces(trim) are there dont send it//
        $.post('ajax/name.php',{id:item}, function(data){   //using post method sending to the father(name.php), sending the data through the file item
            $('div#item-data').append(""+data+"</br>"); // grabing the data and displaying it

        });

    }

$('#item').val('');
 }
 });

});
```

and the third file my name.php file consists of the following code

```
<?php

require '../db/connect.php';

$id= $_POST['id']; // your post variable
$sql = "SELECT BarcodeID, shirts, price FROM clothes WHERE  BarcodeID=".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo " " . $row["BarcodeID"]. " shirt color:  " . $row["shirts"]. "  price: " . $row["price"];
    }
}
else
{
        echo "ID not found, Please Scan again";
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Please use prepared statements, this here: `$sql = "SELECT BarcodeID, shirts, price FROM clothes WHERE BarcodeID=".$id;` opens up a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: google "prepared statements php"

Comment: I have editted my name.php to prevent sql injection. I hope now its fine.

Comment: Yeah, that's great :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by using append function in the javascript. Check in the global.js file.